# Dynamic User-Managed Augmented Reality App

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia, metaio

Im trying to create an app with a very simple but apparently unexplored concept:

I want to be able, throught a website, to upload targets and the multimedia associated to them, and store them in some kind of backend.

Then I want to be able, in my application (lets say android for default, but multi-platform would be neat), to be able to sync my device to the "target-multimedia" database, updating my local storage when changes were detected.

This would allow me to, at any moment, add a new target and associations, through a friendly website client, and suddently every phone with the application would recognize the new target and show the associated multimedia bound to it.

Now, I've been researching alot about the recent technologies that would allow me to achieve such a thing. The main techs of the moment are Vuforia and Metaio, for what I've found.

The problem is that it looks like they are both kinda "static". They are mainly about compiling an already configured dataset of targets and associate stages to them. Vuforia allows for a cloud database but the only thing that it really does is to allow for the same stage to be drawn in additional targets, it doesnt seem to allow the runtime creation of associations.

Metaio also seems to go down a similar path.

It's a fact that I have low experience with both these technologies and I could be wrong, so anyone experienced with AR can put me on the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia's cloud recognition service allows for a large amount of content to be stored with each target in the cloud.  So you can store whatever content you want with each target.

The hard part of what you describe is simply defining *what* the new content is and how it's rendered, which has nothing to do with augmented reality and everything with your rendering system/app logic.

Many systems (including our Argon app) allow arbitrary Html5/JavaScript/webgl webapps to be downloaded and run, for example.  If you use Unity, you could store asset bundles with the targets.

Doing it without the cloud reco service will be harder.  Most AR systems have a limit to the number of target that can be scanned for (100 or so) but their cloud service can scan for many.

Comment: But for what I've seen, Vuforia works by fetching information from the cloud on runtime, which means that if I'm offline, the app doesn't work, right? My goal would be to fetch updates from the cloud whenever I had an internet connection, but then, that info would persist in my device, which apparently adds a whole new level of complexity.

Comment: That's an issue, yes. You could do that, sure, sung sets of targets.  How will you scan for them or choose between them?  With any of these systems, you can only activate ~100 or so targets, so you can't scan for them all at once.  If that doesn't matter (eg, you have some other way to choose which targets to activate) then you could download a bunch ahead of time.  Keep in mind that storage space will also be an issue.

Comment: you could download the assets (the target images) which are close to the user (by using the GPS) and "refresh" this list every time the device is connected to the internet.

Comment: I think you should not mix what an image recognition service provides and the logic of your application. I'm sure that any AR platform allows wrapping their functionality in more complex scenarios, by using programming languages of course. And then why would you not be connected to the internet? This is usually one of the requirements of an image recognition based AR app.